# Scroll UIImageView with UIWebView?

Tags: ios, webview, scrollview

So I've got a UIScrollView that has an image inside, and below that I have a webView. How can I make it so that when I scroll the webView up/down, the scroll view also scrolls up/down? Like when you scroll in Safari, the URL bar moves along with it.

Here's what I'm using:

[image: HatFilms]

Answer (score 1):

- first add the UIWebView and UIScrollView+UIimageView  within an
  another UIScrollVIew
- disable the native scrolling of UIWebView  byt iterating its subviews
- disable the scrolling of the UIScrollView which consists UIImageView

by doing this way will help your cause